# Python pandas dataframe: dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need help in Python pandas dataframe.
I have dataframe in below format(refer Current dataframe) and my requirement is to covert into another data frame in the different format which i have pasted below to it(refer desired dataframe). Can any one help me how can i achieve the desired output.

Current Dataframe

```
Name1                   Name2                       Score
BELFIUS INSURANCE       BELFIUS INSURANCES          0.79
BELFIUS INSURANCE       BELFIUS                     0.50
BELFIUS INSURANCE       BELFIUS T                   0.31
AIR PRODUCTS            AIR PRODUCT                 0.78
AIR PRODUCTS            AIR PRO                     0.63
AIR PRODUCTS            PRODUCTS                    0.39
ARDAGH GLASS            ARDAGH                      0.60
```

Desired dataframe

```
Name1               M1                 Score1    M2        Score2     M3                  Score3
BELFIUS INSURANCE   BELFIUS INSURANCES  0.79    BELFIUS    0.50       BELFIUS T           0.31
AIR PRODUCTS        AIR PRODUCT         0.78    AIR PRO    0.63       PRODUCTS            0.39
ARDAGH GLASS        ARDAGH              0.60    nan        nan        nan                 nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially pivot by one column:

```
out_df = (df.assign(col=df.groupby('Name1').cumcount()+1)
   .pivot_table(index='Name1', columns='col', aggfunc='first')
   .swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
   .sort_index(axis=1)
)
out_df.columns = [f"{y}{x}" if y=="Score" else f"M{x}" for x,y in out_df.columns]
out_df = out_df.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    Name1              M1                    Score1  M2         Score2  M3           Score3
--  -----------------  ------------------  --------  -------  --------  ---------  --------
 0  AIR PRODUCTS       AIR PRODUCT             0.78  AIR PRO      0.63  PRODUCTS       0.39
 1  ARDAGH GLASS       ARDAGH                  0.6   nan        nan     nan          nan
 2  BELFIUS INSURANCE  BELFIUS INSURANCES      0.79  BELFIUS      0.5   BELFIUS T      0.31
```